# execute php file_get_content for limited time and exit

Tags: php, timeout

Is it possible to run php file_get_content for max 25 sec and stop with what ever is received and continue? The goal is to catch the timeout Error.

This will not solve the problem as it only extents the time and at the end fatal error.

```
$opts = array('http' => array('method'  => 'GET', 'timeout' => 120));
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$html = @file_get_contents($crLink, false, $context);
```

Comment: you can set `max_execution_time` of php. Either from php configuration or runtime with `ini_set`.

Comment: @Jigar - extending the time for a non responsive get, leads to fatal error.

Comment: ok. dont know about `file_get_contents` but you can use `curl` and try setting the option [CURLOPT_TIMEOUT](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

Comment: @Jigar - testing curl. But is it possible to archive the goal? "catch the timeout Error"

Comment: what do you mean by timeout error ? I doubt they would throw an exception. You can get the `Content-Length` from header and check if all the contents have been fetched, else its an error.